# Thinking of using a Particle Electron for a process controller

Tags: c, compilation, freertos

As I understand FreeRTOS is merely three C files which reside somewhere on the unit.  If I create some C program, to carry out some specific process.  My question has three parts.

1. Does the C programs have to be compiled externally or is there an interpreter which processes the code when the unit is powered up?
2. If compiled on the unit itself is there a compiler which creates a system type file which then gets booted to start the device?
3. If it has to be created externally, is gcc capable of generating the, I assume, one executable?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about an embedded system:

1. Yes, commonly you need to compile all C files into one executable externally.
2. Well, normally there is no compiler on such a unit. If there is one, its usage and functioning will be documented.
3. This depends on your target system. GCC has a lot of target architectures but you didn't mention yours. Most probably you can't use your PC's GCC because its target is x86 or x64 on Linux or Windows or Mac or such a common system. And your embedded system might be an ARM without an operating system. You need a cross-compiler which you can install.

Comment: Thank you.  It is a Particle Electron unit.  I understand it uses an ARM Cortex M3 32 bit Processor.  It also uses FreeRTOS as its OS.  I can use GCC to cross compile for the ARM processor.  I can probably use the serial method to place the executable on the device once compiled.